# SQL select statement to return lines containing string not just equal to string

Tags: sql, visual-studio, npgsql

I need SQL statement to return all the lines containing the text entered into a search box and not just the ones that are equal to the text entered.

```
SELECT * from table WHERE name='" + this.SearchBoxTxt.Text + "'
```

this only returns the exact matches
I read that you're suppose to use % in order to get the lines containing the string

but

```
SELECT * from table WHERE name='%" + this.SearchBoxTxt.Text + "%'
```

only returns the lines containing the % characters themselves
(for example searching for "test" would return "%test%" as a result)

and

```
SELECT * from table WHERE name=%'" + this.SearchBoxTxt.Text + "'%
SELECT * from table WHERE name='"%  +  this.SearchBoxTxt.Text  + %"'
SELECT * from table WHERE name='" +% this.SearchBoxTxt.Text %+ "'
```

Don't run at all.

What am I missing?

Comment: Imagine a bad guy typing this into your text box: `';DROP TABLE mytable;--` Don't try it, just imagine that someone does that. If this gets your attention, read on SQL injection attacks.

Comment: As for your actual question, use `LIKE instead of `=`.

Comment: wow it was that easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use LIKE instead of = operator. Try something the below:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE name LIKE '%test%'
```

You should concatenate the strings that gives something like above.

Hope it helps!

Comment: While you are correct to use the LIKE operator and the appropriate wild char you are totally wrong about string concatenation. This should never be done instead you should recommend to use parameters.